# Amazon AWS Java SDK example errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run an example for the Amazon Java SDK in eclipse... the SimpleQueueServiceExample but it appears to not be working. Any ideas?

Am getting the following:

WARNING: Failed to initialize regional endpoints from cloudfront
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://d3s62xsdspbbg2.cloudfront.net refused

Oct 09, 2013 4:11:55 PM com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils init
WARNING: Failed to initialize regional endpoints from S3 bucket
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://aws-sdk-configurations.s3.amazonaws.com refused

However the app stops at the breakpoint.. is this normal? Why is this happening?

Comment: On which line did you placed the breakpoint? also, could you try to ping that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Java will try to download an up-to-date configuration file that is uses to map service endpoints to regions. You can check out [this post](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2IHRMVOFHSUO1/Working-with-Different-AWS-span-class-matches-Regions-span) on regions in the Java SDK. As to your question, the SDK has a cached copy of this file and if it cannot get the file from cloudfront, it will use the cached copy and keep going.